# Post to remote WordPress site causing multiple meta keys / meta values

Tags: php, json, wordpress, rest

This code works fine except for a small problem I can't solve:

```
$order   = wc_get_order( $order_id );
$amount  = $order->get_total();
$note    = $order->get_customer_note();

$api_response = wp_remote_post( 'https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts', array(
'headers' => array(
    'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode( 'admin:5mMcJGUGNFYq9PxU5P0ad0Np' )
),
'body' => array(
    'title'         => 'Pink Shirt',
    'status'        => 'publish',
    'post_type'     => 'clothes',
    'categories'    => 2,
    'slug'          => 'pink-shirt',
    'meta'          => array(
        'amount'    => $amount, 
        'note'      => $note, 
        'author'    => 1)
    )
));
```

The problem is, that if any of the variables contain more than one word (`$note` in this particular case), then a meta_key and meta_value gets created in the database for each word.

For example, the customer note is...

`This is a new customer.`

...this is what happens when it is posted to the remote site:

[image]

WTF indeed.

The API response even shows the words as separate items:

[image]

My only 'solution' was to use `str_replace()` to replace all spaces with `&nbsp;`. But that seems crazy to me.

What the heck is going on and how can I solve this?

Comment: (You absolutely, positively have verified that `$note` was not an array to begin with?)

Comment: Only thing I am sure of is that I get the same result if I manually change the `$note` variable to a string like `$note = 'This is a new customer';`

Comment: And it happens for just this one particular meta value? Setting any other value to a similar text, does not show the same problem?

Comment: I would perhaps try and use Postman (https://www.postman.com/) to simulate that same request from the outside, and see if that shows the same issue. If not, then this is either `wp_remote_post` itself behaving strangely for some reason, or one of the WP filters applied somewhere along the line messes up the field data.

Comment: Yes, setting any other value to a similar text does the same thing. I'll look at postman as you suggested and see what I come up with. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by simply doing this: `'note' => array($note)`.

Thanks for your feedback.